# saxon extension function with NODE_SEQUENCE or ANY_SEQUENCE

Tags: saxon, extension-function

I am switching from Saxon 9.3 (PE) to more recent version.
I am using Extension functions (with "extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition")

I have arguments defined as

```
public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {                  
        return new SequenceType[] {SequenceType.ANY_SEQUENCE, SequenceType.ANY_SEQUENCE, SequenceType.NODE_SEQUENCE, SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING};

    }
```

And in the XSLt, the call is made using for exemple a variable on the first argument, which is a built up XML section.

```
<xsl:variable name="graphXML">
                     <CHART>
                           <xsl:attribute name="FORMAT">PNG</xsl:attribute>
                           <xsl:attribute name="HEIGHT">
...
</xsl:variable>
```

Upon call,

```
 private static class GrapheurCall extends ExtensionFunctionCall {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
             public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
```

I needed to change my code because the ExtensionFunctionCall interface changed (previously, I had

```
 public SequenceIterator call(SequenceIterator[] arguments, XPathContext context) throws XPathException { ...
```

)

I have two problems now:

1) The parameter type changed from SequenceIterator to Sequence.
As such

```
NodeInfo dataNode = (NodeInfo) arguments[0].next();
```

could no more be used, and

```
NodeInfo dataNode = (NodeInfo) arguments[0];
```

gives me a runtime error

```
net.sf.saxon.value.SingletonItem cannot be cast to net.sf.saxon.om.NodeInfo
```

though the object received is a TinyTree (as per debug done at runtime).

2) The return value is also different (from SequenceIterator to Sequence)
I had previously 
return new ListIterator(saxon_result);

Which is not possible anymore (saxon_result being a java.util.ArrayList
)
And here, i have no idea how to send back my ArrayList as a sequence...

Can any knowledgeable people shed some light on this?
Thanks!
Fabien

Answer (score 1):

The change from `SequenceIterator` to `Sequence` was made in 9.5, and was part of a general tidy-up that included the introduction of the `Sequence` class to combine the previous `Value` and `ValueRepresentation`. There's a (short) explanation here: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/index.html#!changes/spi/9.4-9.5.1. While we try to minimize disruptive changes like this we generally take the view that when things are wrong and distorting the design of new features, we will put them right at the expense of backwards compatibility.

I'm not sure what release you are using now: the `SingletonItem` class existed in 9.5 but was gone by 9.6; if you're moving forward then I would suggest moving straight to 9.8.

Best practice is to do

```
NodeInfo dataNode = (NodeInfo) argument[0].head();
```

which will work regardless of the internal representation of the argument.

Comment: Hi Michael. 
Thanks, this does work for the NodeInfo.
However, I still have the question regarding the returning value. How can I convert my ArrayList<String> to a sequence? 
I will switch to 9.8 as per your suggestion, since it seems reasonable, however, it did cause another compiling issue, but I assume a new post will be better (method setSource on XPathEvaluator didn't exist. Will make some searching before :) ).

Comment: Simplest is to convert the `List<String>` to a `List<StringValue>` by converting each string, then use `SequenceExtent.makeSequenceExtent(List<T>)`.